# pairing sitecore M/V tests with goals

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms, page-editor

Could some one help in linking my multivariate testing with goals. I have successfully created A/B Testing and everything working fine apart from the value is always Zero. Is sitecore create value automatically or do we need to set goals for the pages to work? As far as i know we need to set goals for the pages.

I have Followed below sitecore documentation which does not talked anything about how to set values for the tests.

http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/marketing_operations_cookbook_sc65-usletter.pdf

Even if we set the goals for a particular page how sitecore going to recognize whether these goals are accomplished by someone coming to that page directly or from the multivariate testing? I am bit confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up two concepts here. Sitecore Engagement Value tracking, and goal conversion. From your question I gather; what you're trying to accomplish is to determine which variation of say a banner or a promotion, generates the most clicks?

You can achieve this, but your content editors are going to have to manage how they work with this. In very simple terms, it would be accomplished in this manner:

- Set up the M/V test, have each of the variations link to different target pages
- On each of the target pages, go to your "Analytics" ribbon, and define "Goals" for the page
- Assign a different goal to each target page in this manner
- Assign each goal an identical value

With these steps in place, and assuming you have no other tests running, this will produce the result you are looking for.

But the point to all of this is - one needs to fully understand what "Engagement Value" means in the Sitecore CEP, and what it can do for you. It's by long and far more than simply determining the highest conversion rate on any one component.

There are tools out there more tailored to the exact scenario you are looking for.

See my answer here: [Clarification on Sitecore A/B Testing Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351138/clarification-on-sitecore-a-b-testing-results/22352411#22352411)
And the SBOS Accellerators kit: http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/SBOS_Accelerators.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's A/B Testing or Multivariate Testing ultimate target is to achieve a conversion So Create a Goal with a value lets say 10 otherwise values will be always zero. for any combination of component if the goal is achieved then for that combination value will be 10 it's called conversion. if conversion not happened for any combination values will never increase. after a long duration of test results will show the best possible combination.

Note : Total value never cross the max value of that goal i e 10. 
Example for a particular combination say 5 times goal reached is Max 10.
for 1 conversion /5 visits, value is 2. 2 conversion /5 visits value is 4.